# Synchronize Android Canvas Surfaceview

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview, synchronized, lag

I am working on an android canvas game and have noticed a lagspike just as the main game form is being drawn. It started just after I started sprinkling `synchronized(surfaceHandler)` around different parts as an attempt to battle concurrent array modification. Did I over synchronize? What is the rule of thumb on when to synchronize and when not to, and when should visible data be modified?

Also is it possible that the spike is caused by something else? The draw method executes while this is happening, but no touch interaction is possible (most, if not all, of the touch method is synchronized).

Advice?

Answer (score 1):

I think that as long as you are generated a canvas from the surface holder in one area, you shouldn't have to synchronize. This may or may not be causing the lagspike. If you are using surfaceHandler in multiple threads, you may want to condense all your drawing into one thread or you will need to keep the synchronize.

Comment: I am only drawing on one thread in one spot, the problem is im modifying collections elsewhere that are being drawn, causing concurrent collection modification. Should these be synchronized? Is ten small synchronizes better/worse/same as one big synchronize?

Comment: I think the overhead for ten "small" synchronizes is worst than one "big" synchronize, with big and small (I'm assuming) corresponds to the number of changes being made. You can also design your data structures to be updated while accessing them, you just can't use iterators :).